# How to un-mirror the armature?

Tags: armature, mirror

I modelled mesh using mirror modifier and and skin modifier. After i applied the mirror modifier,than skin, my armature is also mirrored, 
meaning everything I do on the left is mirrored on the right.
Is it possible that I remove this property, so that I can pose the mesh as I want?

Comment: Are you using pose mode? x-axis mirror is an edit mode option but I don't think there is an automatic mirror option for posing.

Comment: Yes, how to change x-axis mirror in edit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the Armature, go to edit mode, press T to open the Toolshelf, select the option tab, uncheck X mirror.

[image]